# How To Select Max DateTime of the Top 100 Rows Following A Given DateTime

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to find the simplest way of handling the following psudo-sql:

```
SELECT MAX
(
  SELECT TOP 100 
    ModifiedDateTime 
  FROM tableA
  WHERE ModifiedDateTime > @StartDate
)
```

In short, I want to find EndDate of a given batch size given a StartDate.

One option here would obviously be to place the data into a #temp table or another intermediary table:

```
CREATE TABLE #LocalTempTable(
  LastModifiedDateTime DateTime)

INSERT INTO #LocalTempTable
  SELECT TOP(100)
    ModifiedDateTime
  FROM tableA
    WHERE ModifiedDateTime > @StartDate
```

And Extract the max from that table

```
SELECT MAX(ModifiedDateTime)
FROM #LocalTempTable
```

But I'd like a more elegant solution if one exists.

I've also tried to do it with taking the top row of a subquery but it results in a different value than the above #temp table solution:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM
(
  SELECT TOP (100)
    ModifiedDateTime
  FROM tableA
    WHERE ModifiedDateTime > @StartDate
    ORDER BY ModifiedDateTime DESC
) AS EndDate
```

Comment: You are getting different results because you are inconsistently using ORDER BY. The temp table has no order by at all so you are just going to get a random 100 rows. Then in your second attempt you have an order by on the subquery but the main query has no order by so you will just get one of the 100 rows from the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you want something along these lines.

```
SELECT TOP 1 EndDate = ModifiedDateTime FROM
(
  SELECT TOP (100)
    ModifiedDateTime
  FROM tableA
    WHERE ModifiedDateTime > @StartDate
    ORDER BY ModifiedDateTime DESC
) AS x
order by x.ModifiedDateTime desc
```

--EDIT--

As scsimon pointed out this could simplified to this.

```
select top 1 ModifiedDateTime 
from FROM tableA 
WHERE ModifiedDateTime > @StartDate 
ORDER BY ModifiedDateTime DESC
```

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but the sub query isn't needed because no end date is there--so couldn't it be rewritten as `select top 1 ModifiedDateTime from FROM tableA
    WHERE ModifiedDateTime > @StartDate
    ORDER BY ModifiedDateTime DESC`? Just wanting to make sure the OP didn't over complicate this

Comment: @scsimon - LOL you are correct. Since the OP was talking about getting the max date from the top 100 rows I guess I just kept that in the logic and didn't step back to the bigger picture. :D

Comment: I think this is the first time our roles are reversed. Usually you pick these things out way before I do.

Comment: It is all full circle. As they say "it takes a village".

Answer (score 0):

--Use Orderby on all test case that will give you correct answers

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2017-04-01'

; with cte_base (ModifiedDateTime)
AS
(select top 100 ModifiedDateTime
from TableA t
WHERE ModifiedDateTime > @StartDate
ORDER BY ModifiedDateTime DESC
)
SELECT *
FROM cte_base
```